# pointer to a member function of a class

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

I have declared a pointer to member function of a class. It is giving error.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class B
{
public:
    int b;
    void get()
    {
        cin>>b;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b1 ;
    void (B::*ptr)()=&B::get;
    b1.*ptr();
    cout<<b1.b;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pointer-to-member operators `.*` and `->*` have lower precedence than function call syntax. You need to do:

```
(b1.*ptr)();
```